# Where can I find my App Folder when connected to Computer?

Tags: applications, file-system

I need to put a .bak file inside my Application Folder.
I connected my Android Device to my computer via USB, but I cannot locate my App inside any of those folders!

I have unistalled the app and re-installed it again, but still, no folder about it in Nexus7/Android/Data

It is probably a silly question, but I really can't find it. And I need to put those .bak files inside, since they are holding a profile, that needs to be loaded inside my App.

**CAREFUL:** I am not asking where can I find Files that are stored with the OutputStream - but where the FOLDER of Application is located on the Computer, when the Device is connected to it as Media Storage.

Answer (score 1):

Apps' private data directories aren't visible over the USB connection to your PC. It would complicate error handling in apps a lot if you had to worry about users making unexpected changes to your data files, so Android doesn't let you do this, to make it harder for you to screw up your phone.

You can access them from the phone directly, but only if the phone is rooted. If your phone is rooted, you can access any files, but you have to accept the risk of breaking things (this is why it voids the warranty), and it'll make it a lot harder to get support from app vendors. All the same, this is probably using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, and there's probably an easier way to achieve the thing you're trying to, using the facilities built into the app.

Comment: I am open for any suggestion here. I created the App quite some time ago, and it`s quite a big one, so some root modifications to it wouldn't be nice. But now customers want to have their own "Profile" they created to use with App (their background, button colours, etc.).. it is a `bak`file..and I need to include it somehow to my App.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't suggest how to add a "profile" feature to your app. For a start, programming questions are off-topic here; and even if they weren't, you haven't given nearly enough information about the app and what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think I'll go with rooting of the Device then. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I know you can access the app folders (SD/Android/Data) through the Airdroid app - and your browser) but while you can upload files to the folders you can't actually see the files already inside.

Comment: @TrishLing They're only the ones on the SD card, which the OP can see through USB only. In this case I think he's trying to access the internal data directory, which you can't access with any app (without root).

Comment: @Dan Hulme I don't have an SD card slot in either device I use with Airdroid. But yes, it is in the folder labelled SDCard. But after all that is where /Android/Data is.